# Unable to ssh to AWS instance after Cloudformation deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I'm trying to build out a small infrastructure:

- A single VPC
- A single subnet
- A single security group with a single rule: ssh
- A single instance

So far, in order to make it remotely functional I've had to add:

- Internet Gateway
- Route Table

  - Route

When I deploy the template, it creates successfully. I can look through my console and see all of the components.

What I'm having a problem with is connecting to the instance afterward. Attempts to connect via ssh time out.

I think I've narrowed this problem down to the fact that when the stack is built, two route tables are deployed. One is marked as *main* which has no default route added to it, The other one I explicitly define in my template and to which I add the default route.

If I add the default route to the template-define table after the fact, I can ssh.

I guess my questions are:

- how do I mark the table that I'm creating in the template as the main table, or
- how do I tell CloudFormation to not create the *default* table that is being marked as main, or
- how do I get the default route into the main table?

**Template:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  vpcCandidateEyMm7zuOcn:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 192.168.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
        - Key: Test
          Value: Test
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 052446e9-ed29-4689-8eb2-2006482f7a65
  IgCandidateEyMm7zuOcn:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Test
        Value: Test
  AigCandidateEyMm7zuOcn:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
    Properties:
      VpcId: 
        Ref: vpcCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
      InternetGatewayId:
        Ref: IgCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
  RtblCandidateEyMm7zuOcn:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
    Properties: 
      VpcId: 
        Ref: vpcCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
  myRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: IgCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
    Properties:
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: RtblCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId:
        Ref: IgCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
  subnetCandidateEyMm7zuOcn:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 192.168.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'true'
      Tags:
        - Key: Test
          Value: Test
      VpcId: !Ref vpcCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: b9300540-4fb5-4a9c-a432-d12d9a78e08c
  allowSSH:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'Allow SSH from Anywhere'
      VpcId:
        Ref: vpcCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  ansibleInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-4bf3d731
      KeyName: AWSCentOS7
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: !Ref subnetCandidateEyMm7zuOcn
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref allowSSH
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Test
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          pip install ansible
          cd ~
          wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/ansibledepot/web.tar.gz
          tar zxvf web.tar.gz
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 63fffdde-e058-45ad-b2c8-7cf00fd54351
```

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437814/cloudformation-vpc-routing-table-with-no-route-for-internet-gateway?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I had to add the subnet to the route table.

Comment: Please answer your own question, otherwise people will come in here spending their time trying to help with a problem that's already resolved. Suggest you show the CloudFormation code to add the route table, or the finished template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437814/cloudformation-vpc-routing-table-with-no-route-for-internet-gateway?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I had to add the subnet to the route table.

```
    "subnet0RTA": {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
  "Properties" : {
    "RouteTableId" : {"Ref" : "rtb"},
    "SubnetId" : {"Ref" : "subnet0"}
  }
},
"subnet1RTA": {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
  "Properties" : {
    "RouteTableId" : {"Ref" : "rtb"},
    "SubnetId" : {"Ref" : "subnet1"}
  }
},
```